# How to disable scrolling in Intel AppFramework UI side menu

Tags: menu, scroll, intel, appframework

The question is in the title ;).
I tried **style="overflow:hidden"** as for panels, but it did not work.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Got response from Intel team.
Just add :

```
$.ui.scrollingDivs.menu_scroller.disable();
```

immediatly after :

`$.ui.launch();`

Comment: do you know how to enable independent side scrolling on a left or right menu?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ui.scrollingDivs.menu_scroller.verticalScroll = false;
```

It is working without $.ui.launch();